# How to protect my application from task killers?

Tags: android, kill-process

My application (audio player), after starting any task killer incorrectly ends the process. The notification does not disappear from the notification bar and after click on it, the application crash. I want that my application does not stopped and closed. Is it possible to implement the protection of my application from task killers applications?

Comment: I think there is a reason why your app is getting killed. Rather fix the app. Find out why its crashing

Comment: No.  You should write your app so that it does not crash if this happens.  Task killers use Android methods which you can't control.  BTW.  Task Killers are evil.  Do everything you can to stop the evil...

Comment: Thank you.  When the application is closed using task killers what some methods are called in my application? For example something like OnDestroy?

Comment: In my case default Android task killer is working correctly but the third party Task killers are not...